# sort according to the numeric value at the end before file extention ".png"

Tags: python, sorting, alphanumeric

```
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        print(f)
```

results in:

```
    TSR23_kaji_v004_10.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_100.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_1000.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_11.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_12.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_13.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_14.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_15.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_16.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_200.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_99.png
```

here my main problem is it doesn't sorts according to the digit in the last before the extension ".png"

I want to have output as follows:

```
    TSR23_kaji_v004_10.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_11.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_12.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_13.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_14.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_15.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_16.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_99.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_100.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_200.png
    TSR23_kaji_v004_1000.png
```

Please guide me to get the results

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are seeing the results in alphabetic order, not numeric order.  '10' < '1000' < '11'.   This is the standard order on every OS that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to extract the last number and convert it from a string to a number. A [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is one way to extract the text. For example, one or more digits followed by a `.png` character can be found with:

```
import re

def get_last_int(s):
    return int(re.search(r'\d+(?=\.png)', s).group())
```

Passing it one of your strings gives the int:

```
get_last_int('TSR23_kaji_v004_200.png')
# 200
```

With that, you can use `sorted()` to sort based on the integers in question:

```
import re


def get_last_int(s):
    return int(re.search(r'\d+(?=\.png)', s).group())

l = ['TSR23_kaji_v004_10.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_100.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_1000.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_11.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_12.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_13.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_14.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_15.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_16.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_200.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_99.png']


sorted(l, key=get_last_int)
# ['TSR23_kaji_v004_10.png',
#  'TSR23_kaji_v004_11.png',
#  'TSR23_kaji_v004_12.png',
#  'TSR23_kaji_v004_13.png',
#  'TSR23_kaji_v004_14.png',
#  'TSR23_kaji_v004_15.png',
#  'TSR23_kaji_v004_16.png',
#  'TSR23_kaji_v004_99.png',
#  'TSR23_kaji_v004_100.png',
#  'TSR23_kaji_v004_200.png',
#  'TSR23_kaji_v004_1000.png']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`natsort`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/howitworks.html):

```
# pip install natsort
from natsort import natsorted

l = ['TSR23_kaji_v004_10.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_100.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_1000.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_11.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_12.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_13.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_14.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_15.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_16.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_200.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_99.png']


out = natsorted(l)
```

Output:

```
['TSR23_kaji_v004_10.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_11.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_12.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_13.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_14.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_15.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_16.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_99.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_100.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_200.png',
 'TSR23_kaji_v004_1000.png']
```